# How to update associated models in gem "devise" account_update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm new in ruby on rails

I use gem "devise" for authentication users and I have trouble with update assosiated models in account update action. At account update, keys 'user_id' in assosiated records set to nil

database queries that occurs:

```
UPDATE "user_information" SET "user_id" = ? WHERE "user_information"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", nil], ["user_id", 1]]
UPDATE "user_settings" SET "user_id" = ? WHERE "user_settings"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", nil], ["user_id", 1]]
```

ie request reset key user_id to nil in associated models. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

migrations

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
  # etc
end

create_table :user_settings, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :user, null: false, index: true, unique: true
  # etc
end

create_table :user_information, :id => :user_id do |t|
  t.references :user, null: false, index: true, unique: true
  # etc
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting, :class_name => 'User::Setting', inverse_of: :user
  has_one :information, :class_name => 'User::Information', inverse_of: :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :information'

  # devise
end
```

registrations controller

```
class Users::Devise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,
           information_attributes: [:name, :contacts], setting_attributes: [:monetization])
        # etc
    end
  end

  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    super
    self.resource.build_setting
    self.resource.build_information if hash.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: Kindly explain your problem in more detail. I can see your code but I do not get what is to be done.

What is the expected behaviour? And what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: Your query is updating your user setting tables and you don't why. Is that your question? Sorry for not being clear with your question.

Comment: @Vitaly What is the right thing that should happen here? Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate description of the subject matter. I try again. I want to update user information/settings tables, but when i do this, user_id in those tables sets to nil. This is the problem